# Replaced Nvidia GTX 460 with RX 460 and AMDGPU not being used

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I recently upgraded my PC with an AMD RX 460, replacing a Nvidia GTX 460. I was originally using the Nvidia binary drivers (using the additional drivers GUI). I uninstalled these (through the GUI) and inserted the RX 460. Now I'm fairly certain the AMDGPU drivers are not installed for several reasons -

1. Only 1 monitor works when I have three connected
2. running `inxi -Gx` gives:

   ```
   Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 67ef bus-ID: 08:00.0
          Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: vesa,radeon)
          Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
          GLX Renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 128 bits)
          GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.4 Direct Rendering: Yes
   ```
3. running `xrandr --listproviders` returns:

   ```
   Providers: number : 0
   ```
4. It's very laggy

[Update]

When I start Ubuntu from a liveusb, graphics performance seems to be much better, so I'm gathering that it was the Nvidia drivers which have messed things up somehow. When I run xrandr --listproviders, I get this instead (which seems to be correct):

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x57 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:AMD Radeon RX 460 Graphics @ pci:0000:08:00.0
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just reinstalling Ubuntu since that fixed the problem.